# interactive zoom in rendered figure

Tags: rascal

After generating and displaying a large figure using `vis::Figure` and `vis::Render`, is there a way to interactively zoom out/in, in the Eclipse window showing the figure?

I tried `<Control>+<mouse-wheel>`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that functionality is not implemented in that version of the Figure library. There exist an experimental web-based version here, with a similar interface but different and more behaviors: https://github.com/cwi-swat/shapes

Comment: But note that the shapes library does non support general zooming either.

Comment: Wouldn't the browser  help with that?